# Aligning icons within Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a web site that uses Bootstrap 3. In that web site, I have a drop down menu. Each item in the menu consists of an icon and a name. My challenge is, my icons are not laid out properly. The icons are not in line and the text is not in line. It looks disjointed. My HTML looks like this:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
  <li><a target="_blank" href="/User/Create"><span class="fa fa-user-plus" style="margin-right: 10px;"></span>Add User</a></li>
  <li><a target="_blank" href="/User/Edit"><span class="fa fa-user" style="margin-right: 10px;"></span>Edit User</a></li>
  <li><a target="_blank" href="/User/Delete"><span class="fa fa-user-times" style="margin-right: 10px;"></span>Delete User</a></li>
  <li><a target="_blank" href="/Buiding/Add"><span class="fa fa-building" style="margin-right: 10px;"></span>Building</a></li>
</ul>
```

What am I doing wrong? What do I have to do to get my icons and text to line up?

Comment: Can't say without a demo, or at least a screenshot. My best wild guess is that text wraps due to inadequate horizontal space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard without an example, but something you can try is adding an height to the `<li>` element (for example 60px), adding `display:block`, `width:100%`,`height:100%` and `line-height` the same as the height you set on the `<li>` element (60px in our example)

try, this could help you a bit.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the class `fa-fw` to set icons at a fixed width.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
  <li><a target="_blank" href="/User/Create"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user-plus"></i>&nbsp; Add User</a></li>
  <li><a target="_blank" href="/User/Edit"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user"></i>&nbsp; Edit User</a></li>
  <li><a target="_blank" href="/User/Delete"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user-times"></i>Delete User</a></li>
  <li><a target="_blank" href="/Buiding/Add"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-building"></i>&nbsp; Building</a></li>
</ul>
```

Doc : http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/#fixed-width